# In Drupal 7 Views 3, is there a way to change "Access" under "Page Settings" to use a custom access function?

Tags: views

I have a senario where I would like Views to either allow me to use a custom Access control or allow me to specify some logic such as "This or This". So for instance, I could write a function

```
return (user_access('Permission 1') || user_access('Permission 2'));
```

Any suggestions?

Maybe a custom views access handler? If this is the option... anyone got a good link to an example access handler?

Comment: This approach looks promising: http://techcp.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/adding-custom-access-plugin-to-views-in-drupal/

Comment: If I had the ability to, I would +1 your comment sir. I did end up writing a custom handler, but I modled mine more closely to one from OG.